# Why are there still words that don't fit criterion in my list

Tags: python, list

Im trying to take a list with all 5 letter words and remove all words that have any of the letters in qwerty.

I tried this:

```
words = [apple, rusty, cloud]

new_words = []
bad = ['q','w','e','r','t','y']
for word in words:
    num = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in bad:
            num+=1
        else:
            num+=0
    if num==5:
        new_words.append(word)
            
print(len(new_words))
```

when words contains all 14,855 words, it returns 5786 when it should be 3217

Comment: How is `bad` defined?

Comment: @Chris I think that's "words that have any of the letters in qwerty".

Comment: You need to provide a **short** but **complete** example program that we can run ourselves, so we can produce the same results.  Update the code to contain an actual value for `bad`, and hardcode `words` to be a list of a few sample words.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: Your sample code also needs to **demonstrate the error behavior**.  This code correctly identifies "cloud" as the only word that does not contain qwerty, so it does not actually **demonstrate the issue**.

Comment: I suspect your actual words list contains some words that are longer than five letters...

Answer (score 0):

Set intersections make this pretty straightforward:

```
>>> [
...   word 
...   for word in ["hello", "world", "foooo", "foo"] 
...   if len(word) == 5
...   if not (set(word) & set("qwerty"))
... ]
['foooo']
```

You will want to make sure all of the words you're checking are lowercased.

Comment: Could also use `filter(set("qwerty").isdisjoint, words)`, which is more efficient. (But that wouldn't answer the question, either.)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in youre requirements that says you should count the number of non-qwerty characters. Just check if the word has any of them, using the `any()` function.

```
for word in words:
    if not any(letter in word for letter in bad):
        new_words.append(word)
```

or as a list comprehension:

```
new_words = [word for word in words if not any(letter in word for letter in bad)]
```

Comment: i dont need to see if the word is 5 letters since all the words in the list are 5 letters

Comment: Before the edit it wasn't clear that the input was only 5-letter words, I thought that was part of the filtering.

Comment: Hmm, I see that stated *twice* in the original version...

Comment: I misunderstood "take a list" as "make a list". And the original code was testing if the count was equal to 5.

Comment: @KellyBundy I only see "take a list with all 5 letter words". Where is the *second* place?

Comment: `#words is a list with ~14000 5 letter words`

Comment: @KellyBundy Since when do comments count? :)